# tsc and ng build does nothing, no response at all after Angular update

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

After I have updated my project to Angular 11 by following the angular update guide, the `ng build` and `tsc` commands just give back the prompt and nothing happens.
If I try `npm run build` it gives me the following logfile. I have included my package.json. `tsc -v` is Version 4.3.5, `ng version` says Angular is 11.2.14.

**Update 1**

I have included the output of `tsc --extendedDiagnostics` that shows files: 0. Is it normal?

What else should I try? Where can I get more information?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\ppppp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.17.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~prebuild: MyApp@0.14.0
6 info lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: MyApp@0.14.0
7 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: PATH: ***
9 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\ppppp\Dev\SNC\MyApp\src\MyApp\ClientApp
10 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng build' ]
11 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: Returned: code: 3  signal: null
12 info lifecycle MyApp@0.14.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: MyApp@0.14.0 build: `ng build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ppppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ppppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid MyApp@0.14.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\ppppp\Dev\SNC\MyApp\src\MyApp\ClientApp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ppppp\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.17.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
22 error MyApp@0.14.0 build: `ng build`
22 error Exit status 3
23 error Failed at the MyApp@0.14.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

All packages updated to v11 or their dependecies:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.14.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run MyApp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.26",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.15.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.14",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.15",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-translate-extract": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  }
}
```

**tsc --extendedDiagnostics**

```
Files:                          0
Lines of Library:               0
Lines of Definitions:           0
Lines of TypeScript:            0
Lines of JavaScript:            0
Lines of JSON:                  0
Lines of Other:                 0
Nodes of Library:               0
Nodes of Definitions:           0
Nodes of TypeScript:            0
Nodes of JavaScript:            0
Nodes of JSON:                  0
Nodes of Other:                 0
Identifiers:                    0
Symbols:                        7
Types:                         59
Instantiations:                 0
Memory used:               20042K
Assignability cache size:       0
Identity cache size:            0
Subtype cache size:             0
Strict subtype cache size:      0
I/O Read time:              0.00s
Parse time:                 0.00s
Program time:               0.13s
printTime time:             0.00s
Emit time:                  0.00s
Total time:                 0.13s
```

Comment: maybe you have to update node globally? wich version are you using?

Comment: @Dario Sorry, forgot to mention that I have just updated node as well to 14.17.2